# How to set to-one relationship to other element, when previous element was deleted?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have two Core Data entities: Asset and Image. An Asset has both, a To-Many and a To-One relationship to Image. See diagram:

[image: To-Many and To-One relationship]

For the domain, Asset>keyImage must be one of the Asset>images, so if an image is deleted from Asset>images, this image can no longer be the keyImage and keyImage becomes nil. (I have that part working).

If Asset>keyImage becomes nil (is deleted), i want to set it automatically to one of the other images in Asset>images, if there are any.

My question is about where to put the code that does set the keyImage to the next image in Asset>image. I was thinking about:

- overriding `(void)removeImagesObject:(Image *)value;` in the `NSManagedObject` subclass of `Asset`, or i tried to
- register the `Asset` subclass of `NSManagedObject` as an observer `[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"keyImage" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:&assetContextForKVO];` to itself. Here i had half the time success, half the time i got "repairing missing delete propagation“ errors from Core Data.

Or somewhere completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Asset has a set of Images (as implied by the to-many relationship) then it knows about all of the Images that are available to itself. If the keyImage is deleted from Image then when your code references Asset, it should check to see if keyImage is nil. If yes, then it should choose another image from the images (relationship) set and set it as keyImage. SQLite cannot automagically do this for you, just like it cannot arbitrarily assign Images to your Asset.

```
@interface Asset : NSManagedObject
//...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *images;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Image *keyImage;
//...
@end

@interface MyViewController
//...
// fetch an asset object then
if (self.asset.keyImage == nil && [self.asset.images count] > 0)
    [self.asset addImagesObject:[asset.images anyObject]];
@end
```

Comment: Thank you. I know how to set the new keyImage — i just don’t know, where to put this code. I clarified my question above. So you would put it to the ViewController? In what method would you put it?

Comment: I would put the code to assign the new keyImage in the same method you are using to delete the Image(s). Also, I would only delete Images through the Asset relationship. In other words, I wouldn't go straight to Image and start deleting Image objects. I would 1) fetch the Asset; 2) delete images from the Asset relationship via

Comment: asset.images; 3) check asset.keyImage == nil or better yet as you are deleting the asset.images, compare the Image object you are deleting against if (asset.keyImage == myImageToDelete) and flag that you need to grab a new keyImage after you finish deleting Images; 4) assign a new keyImage via the code above [asset.images anyObject]

Comment: Ok, i added the functionality to my NSArrayController subclass in the `remove:` method.